# wait for response from api for 5 sec if response taking time put in console log

Tags: javascript, angular

IF api taking time then it should notify within 5 sec

```
const result = await API.methodForAPI()
```

// if Noresponse from API in 5 sec show alert
if(result)

Comment: Could you please edit your question and add more info? What you are looking for? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with [Promise.race](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/race), to find what returns first, the API call or the 5 sec timeout.

```
var p1 = fetch('https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2');
var p2 = new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{ setTimeout(resolve, 5000, new Error('timeout'))
```

```js
var p1 = fetch('https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2')
var p2 = new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{ setTimeout(resolve, 5000, new Error('timeout')); });

Promise.race([p1,p2]).then((res)=>{
  if(res instanceof Error) {
      console.warn(res);
  } else {
     res.json().then((users)=> {
         console.log(users);
     });
  }
})
```

; })